# formsy-react getting Uncaught TypeError: _formsyReact2.default.addValidationRule is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, formsy-react

I have been trying to run react starter kit with formsy-react, I see babel converts it to formsyrect2.addvalidationRule to formsyrect2.default.addvalidationRule.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I see Formsy.addValidationRule is searching for _formsyReact2.default.addValidationRule

Comment: Pls show your react components, otherwise it's impossible to help you out.

Comment: I have updated the question, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It converts it into `default` import cause you are used that syntax, it should be `import * as Formsy from 'formsy-react';`